# RegionErosion fails with Polygon

Tags: regions, polygons

I would like to use `RegionErosion` to erode a `Polygon`. This example from the docs works:

```mathematica
With[{reg = StadiumShape[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}, 2]},
 Show@{
   Region[
    Style[reg, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Dashed]]
    ]
   ,
   Region[
    RegionErosion[reg, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
    ]
   }
 ]
```

[image: works]

However, changing the region from a "stadium shape" to a Polygon fails:

```mathematica
With[{reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}}]},
 Show@{
   Region[
    Style[reg, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Dashed]]
    ]
   ,
   Region[
    RegionErosion[reg, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
    ]
   }
 ]
```

[image: error]

Both shapes are Regions:

[image: regions]

And wrapping the `Polygon` in `Region` produces the same error.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `RegionErosion[reg, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]`.

Comment: This returns `EmptyRegion[1]`, the empty subset of R^1. This is surprising because our shapes are 2-dimensional, not 1, so I'd expect `EmptyRegion[2]` here. I see that `RegionEmbeddingDimension` returns 2 for the Polygon and the Line you suggested.

Comment: You're right, Justin, there's something weird about that.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use `RegionDilation` for `Line[-{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]`.

```
With[{reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}}]}, 
 Show@{Region[
    Style[reg, FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.2], Green]], 
     EdgeForm[Dashed]]], 
   Region[Style[RegionDilation[reg, Line[-{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], 
     FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], EdgeForm[]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, interesting idea, except I'm trying to erode the polygon, which should result in a smaller polygon. In your example, your green polygon has dilated into a larger blue shape. I am not sure that you can use RegionDilation to result in a _smaller_ shape.

Comment: @ConvexMartian `RegionErosion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]] == 
 RegionDilation[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Line[-{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]`

Comment: @ConvexMartian  Or your example `With[{reg = StadiumShape[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}, 2]}, 
 Show@{Region[Style[reg, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Dashed]]], 
   Region[RegionDilation[reg, Line[-{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]]}]`